# Convert multiple csv files to Excel files?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, openpyxl

In Python 2.7, I have a lot of csv files I want to convert to Excel.
The names of the csv files are `abcd1.csv`, `abcd2.csv` and so on.
I want to convert them to `abcd1.xls`, `abcd2.xls` and so on.
While I am able to do it on one file, I don't know how to do it on multiple files.

This is the function I have used so far:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
file_name = "COUNT16_DISTRIBUTION" + str(count3*1) + ".csv"
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save()
```

the file_name can be used in a while loop and I can go through each csv file but I dont know how to save them as `.xls`.

Comment: does https://superuser.com/questions/301431/how-to-batch-convert-csv-to-xls-xlsx do the job?

Comment: Another solution would be to use `pandas`.

Comment: Turn your code into a function and use either `glob.glob()` or `os.listdir()` to determine the files you need to pass to the new function.

Comment: @hennich, i checked the link- apparently they are converting all csv files in a directory into a single xls file

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Create function that converts csv 2 excel
def csv2excel(filepath, sep=','):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=sep)
    newpath = os.path.splitext(filepath)[0] + '.xlsx'
    df.to_excel(newpath, index=False)

# Loop through files and call the function
for f in os.listdir('.'):
    if f.endswith('.csv') and f.startswith('abcd'):
        csv2excel(f)
```

Comment: In the if loop, in case if ii have a lot of csv files how can i replace 'f.endswith' with something to take the names of multiple csv files ? There are a lot of csv files but i dont want to touch all of them. I want to touch only the ones with the given name . i am trying filename = "COUNT16_DISTRIBUTION" + str(count3*1) + ".csv"              and then in the for loop i increment and check for the next file in the directory.

Comment: there is a pattern abcd1.csv, abcd2.csv, abcd3.csv and so on this is the pattern and i want to save it as abcd1.xls, abcd2.xls etc. In my initial code i was able to do it but when i would open the xls file it would be corrupt.

Comment: @anvinder How about adding `f.startswith('abcd')`, see edited code.

Comment: I tried the startswith and it gives an error : "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file" in the line : df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=sep)

Comment: Converting from CSV to Excel via Pandas is not particularly advisable because this means going from rows to columns to rows.